# Firebase notification_receive not showing up in events in Firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

We have recently started using FCM as our notification service , We are using batch process to send notifications to Android and IOS through FCM. Problem is notification_recieve event is not showing up in the events tab of firebase analytics event tab in android app. As per as documentation this event should be logged automatically for android app.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for the notification events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485) all contain the phrase "when sent by Firebase Notifications".

For example: ***notification_receive*** -- when a notification sent by Firebase Notifications is received by a device when the app is in the background

My tests indicate "sent by Firebase Notifications" means "sent from the Notification panel of the Firebase Console". The events are not generated when the notifications are created by posting data to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`.